# Upload large email attachments to owncloud in mu4e

Tags: mu4e, attachment

When composing/sending messages, I would like to automatically upload large attachments to my owncloud server, similar to what the Thunderbird AddOn https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/owncloud-for-filelink/ does.

I'm aware that probably this functionality doesn't exist yet, but is anybody aware of any building blocks I could use in implementing such a package?

Answer (score 1):

In elisp:

- defines URL + destination domain settings
- run the `<select file>` emacs process
- `exec` the file upload using `cadaver/lftp/netrc/...`
- grab/build the destination file-link (may need to use the ownCloud Share API)
- paste URL at emacs under cursor

Or alternatively start with a simple alias which, for a given file (or directory) uploads it and returns the public destination URL (cf ownCloud share API to grab a unique link).
Then just call this wrapper from elisp.

Comment: That does not seem to satisfy the "automatically" criteria of the question.